# Show overlay in background when hovering over parent menu items

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a CSS based dropdown menu, created within Wordpress using their menus. I'm trying to add a jQuery overlay div to be shown when a parent menu item is hovered, and the child menu shown.

I've found the following JSFiddle that helped, and that my code is based upon http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/28/ , but I changed the selector from `ul` to `#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item` so it would stay open whilst hovered on the entire sub menu.

[image: Site without hover]
Abive is the site when not hovered, and below is when a parent menu item is hovered:
[image: Site with hover]

Technically, it works, and the overlay div is shown/hidden. But when I hover to the next parent item with the overlay shown, it disappears when it should stay visible IE. if I then hover over 'BODY', the new sub menu appears, but the overlay disappears.

This example can be seen on the JSFiddle by changing the element from `ul` to `li`. Then when you hover from one `li` to the other, the overlay disappears.

How can I adapt the JS code so that the overlay will continue to show when I move from one parent menu item, to the next?

PS. If a menu item has a child menu below it, the classes `menu-item-has-children` and `menu-parent-item` are added to the `li`

This is my JS code I'm using:

```
(function($) {
$('#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item').hover(function(){
    $('#menu_overlay').fadeTo(200, 1);
}, function(){
    $('#menu_overlay').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to find what I was looking for by using the following code, which seemed to be alot simpler.

```
(function($) {
$("#menu-main-menu > .menu-parent-item").hover(function(){
    $('#menu_overlay').fadeToggle();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Although when going from one parent item to another, the overlay fades out, and then in again.. at least the overlay remains when moving from item to item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this completely in CSS.

Don't hide `darkness`, but give it an opacity of 0 in the rgba, and add a 0.2s transition:

```
#darkness {
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 0.2s;
}
```

When hovering the `ul`, change the opacity of `darkness` to 0.5:

```
ul:hover + #darkness {
  background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
```

You can use a different `hover` on the `li`s to show submenus:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Home
    <ul>
      <li>Submenu 1
      <li>Submenu 2
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zggpgs33/)

Comment: @RichHitchcock Actually, I'm not sure this is all that great, as this means the overlay div is always visible, and is ontop of everything else on the site, which makes nothing clickable. The overlay div needs to be hidden when not seen, ie. display set to none.

Comment: In that case, give the overlay div a negative z-index.  Its background will still function as normal, but you can interact with elements on top of it.  In my first fiddle, try to select "Some text here."  Impossible.  Now try with this fiddle, which has uses a negative z-index:  http://jsfiddle.net/nrdcrss8/

Comment: Hmm, thanks and I appreciate your help, but I'm not convinced about the CSS only route, as the initial triggering from hover events does't seem to be working anyway.